# Custom JSON array deserialization in Jackson

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, deserialization

I need to to deserialize json property (field) absolutely my way using `org.codehaus.jackson`. I know about custom `@JsonDeserializer` option, but this is only useful, if you need to deserialize given values of array. I need to deserialize values of array and array itself. To be concrete I need to deserialize `ForreignCollection` from ORMLite, so I should be able to programatically create `ForeignCollectionField` and add values into it.

```
@JsonProperty
@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<PerformerLocalized> localized;
```

Are there any ideas, how to manage it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@JsonDeserialize` can be used BOTH container AND values, like so:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=MyContainerDeserializer.class, // this would apply to Collection
   contentUsing=ValueDeserializer.class) // and this to value type
```

note that normally `Collection` deserializers do not deal with values, but just delegate it (to make things nicely modular). But you can obviously choose differently with your deserializer; either delegate or directly deal with. If you want to delegate, you probably want to implement `ContextualDeserializer` interface, to be able to resolve delegatee deserializers.